# How can i exit the for statement in assembly

Tags: assembly, msp430

The purpose of this code is to flash the bits turned on  three times, exit the loop and turn them off. Currently the code seems to be in an infinite loop and does not exit the loop after the count is 0

```
                   mov.b   #0x00,&P2REN ;

                   mov.b   #0xFF,&P2OUT ;
                   ;mov.b   #3, r5
                   .bss    i,3 





                                     mov.w   #3,&i        ; 



                   dec.w   &i           ; i--,
                   jnz     for          ; back to for loop
  for_Done:

                    delayloop:                 dec.w   r15          ;
                   jnz     delayloop    ;jump if not zero to delayloop
                   jmp     for         ;jump to the for
                   ;jmp    for_Done
```

Comment: asm doesn't have "for statements".  You simply have a label called `for` on a loop.  Make the branch at the bottom conditional, so it falls through when some counter or whatever reaches some condition.

Comment: I have updated with the code, i did a version in C and it does what i intended for this Assembly code. I would just like to know how can i exit the label "for". I understand that it is with a condition but when i = 0 it still doesn't exit the loop

Comment: Have you single-stepped with a debugger to verify that it doesn't fall through?  You have an unconditional `jmp` back to `for:` later, so obviously you need to jump over that `jmp` if you want execution to continue somewhere past there.  Also, why are you keeping `i` in memory, instead of in a register?

Comment: The comments regarding the pull-up resistors are wrong. Please show the original C code.

Answer (score 1):

Like @PeterCordes mentioned, the last command is an unconditional jump to the loop.

That loop decrements the variable `i` which is 0 after the jump from the end to the loop. It will **not** be initialized with 3 again. After decrement i in the loop, it will be negative and will stay so for more than 32000 Iterations (w=16Bit?). Than it goes on to the last jump and all will start from new.

Do you really need the last jump? You can be sure that `i == 0` if you reach this code.